# How to integrate api with gitlab on swaggerhub dashboard?

Tags: rest, gitlab, swagger

I have some rest APIs on my SwaggerHub dashboard. How to integrate them with my Gitlab repository?

I clicked the import API button on the left top side and input the url of my gitlab repository. But there occurs 403 error.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "integrate"? Do you mean one-time import of your OpenAPI YAML/JSON documents from GitLab into SwaggerHub? Or one-time export of OpenAPI documents from SwaggerHub into GitLab? Or bi-directional sync of OpenAPI documents? Or something else?

Comment: I want to update the document on SwaggerHub automatically when the document on Gitlab is changed.